# Excel row sampling

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table with a large number of rows.

I would like to take a random sample of say 100 rows and hide the rest, say display 1 row per 500 rows or completely random selection of the entire worksheet works also.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Prasanna Looking for a simple and fast visualization of some csv data which I have prepared, using excel's conditional formatting

Answer (score 6):

You could add a random number column, using the formula `=RAND( )` with nothing in-between the parenthesis:

[image: Using '=RAND( )' formula]

Copy the formula down the entire dataset so all rows are populated. Then you can use 'Number Filters' and select 'Top 10':

[image: Number Filters Menu]

Change the value to '100' and the filter will select the 'Top 100' random values. The result will be a random sample of 100 rows.  There may be a better or easier way, but that would work.

Comment: thanks, simple and quick to implement. I have one question, would the random values be recalculated each time I open the spreadsheet? And if so, any ways to resolve this

Comment: using the macro approach,  name a cell update and use it to decide when it needs to work.  If going with the formula, then it is more tricky. Instead of the builtin rand function you will need to make your own psuedo-random (assume have a cell named seed, a cell named Pcode, and another named step) =+IF(ROW()=2,seed,MOD(step+B1,PCode)) This allows you to recreate the exact "random" configuration again by setting the same seed, step, and PCode.

Comment: Nice update to the formula from bvaughn! Or, if you need the random sample to be static, perhaps you could simply duplicate the sample data. I.e once the random 100 is filtered, CTRL+A to select the range and copy/past in to a separate worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is based completely on ***batesan***'s excellent approach *(which this macro automates)*.

Say we started with a single column and, following batesan's suggestion, added a column of `=RAND()`:

[image]

In my simple example, the table has only *18* entries and I want to select *3* at random.

Running the short macro:

```
Sub PickThree()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1:B19")

    If sh.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter Field:=2
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    Calculate
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="3", Operator:=xlTop10Items
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

Each time the macro is re-run, a new set of three random rows are picked!